# Prevent User from Type English in input and Force to type in Hebrew

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hebrew

I have script that prevent user from typing **hebrew** in input, and to force him to type in **english**.
I want to achive the oppeset way:
I want to **prevent** the user from typing **english** and **force** him to type in **hebrew**.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="j-row">
  <div class="span6 unit">
   <div class="input">
     <span >Surname:</span>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="surename">   
    </div>
   </div>                    
<div class="span6 unit">
  <div class="input">
     <span>Name:</span>
        <input type="text" id="nameheb" name="nameheb" placeholder="full name">
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript (jquery 1.9.1):

```
$("#name,#surname").keypress(function(event){
    var ew = event.which;
    if(ew == 32)
        return true;
    if(48 <= ew && ew <= 57)
        return true;
    if(65 <= ew && ew <= 90)
        return true;
    if(97 <= ew && ew <= 122)
        return true;
    return false;
});
```

The hebrew characters goes from 1488 to 1522. [**See here**](http://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/languages/mideast/hebrew/hebrewchart/).
But i cant get them to work properly.

Any idea how to manage that?

Here's live one: **[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rami7250/nd0x8cmj/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to adjust the condition to just allow hebrew chars.

You may also consider to show the user a hint that the english char he typed was not accepted, otherwise it could get confusing.

```
if(1488 <= ew && ew <= 1522){
    return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nd0x8cmj/1/